# How get Eclipse to find attributes and methods?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio

I finish my evaluation of PhpStorm and I got back do Zend Studio today.
When implementing my classes and methods I can't get the Zend Studio find methods, classes and not even php built-in functions. For example: I am extending from TestCase from PHPUnit and the IDE can't find methods any methods within $this. It can't find even attributes in the same class. I mean to find all of those using Ctrl + Space.

How can I get the Eclipse Zend Studio to find all those attributes, methods, functions that PhpStorm found, using Ctrl + Space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Studio is no longer maintained, but Eclipse PHP plugin still breathing, we recently moved to GitHub.

To have any Code Assist / Validation in PHP file, you need:

1. Configured PHP project
2. File inside Source Path (previously called Build Path).

See more in help: https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/topic/org.eclipse.php.help/html/tasks/creating_php_projects.html

If you have any issue, ask here: https://github.com/eclipse/pdt

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I was creating the project as a "general" project instead of a PHP Project. Reading your answer gave me that idea and the referencing works now on Zend Studio.